# Chart.js v3.7.1 Chart is not a Constructor

Tags: javascript, html, constructor, chart.js, typeerror

I am following a Youtube tutorial on chart.js (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE08f4iuOhA 9:05 point of error on my code) when they look at their webpage with the graph it shows up with no errors, however when I attempt to recreate this, I run into "Uncaught TypeError: Chart is not a Constructor". I'm not sure where I went wrong here.
 I've tried changing var to let, adding dimensions on the canvas tag, and reverting the Chart.js version to a lower, possibly more stable version as many forum posts have recommended but to no avail I keep running into this this issue and it is leading me to believe its an over looked error in my code. Which is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Graph</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            let Chart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            let line = new Chart(myChart, {
                type:'line',
                data:{
                    labels:[],
                    datasets:[
                        1,
                        2,
                        3,
                        4,
                        5,
                        99,
                    ],
                },
                options:{}
            
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the second tutorial I've run into this issue on, I was following the chart.js Getting Started guide but my chart was not appearing (assuming same issue or similar, I didn't think of f12 debug (embarrassingly until the seconds time I had the issue) ), so I moved to a video tutorial only to run into my chart not appearing again. I'm trying to learn how to using graphs this way for a project at school and its beginning to be very frustrating.
I am running this on Flask Server on a Raspberry Pi.
I am hoping someone can provide some insight on what I'm doing wrong (I am very new to webpage building)!
 Cheers!

Comment: Noticed version is wrong in my code this is the one I reverted to. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a name clash in your code. You defined a variable `Chart`, which is also the name of the main class from Chart.js. You could rename your variable to `ctx` for example.

Also, `data.labels` should have the same number of entries as `data.datasets.data`. Further keep in mind that `data.datasets` is an array of objects. Additional information is available [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html).

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    datasets: [{      
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 99]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: I added this but I'm still getting Chart is not a constructor...

Comment: instead of `let Chart = ...` ,use `let ctx = ...`, then create your chart as follows: `new Chart(ctx, { ...` or simply `new Chart('myChart', { ...` as I did.